# Java program runs fine within Netbeans, but when running from a built JAR it does not work

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, jdbc, netbeans-7.2

I am a total noob at java at the moment, and all I am trying to do is add MySQL logging to this Java Proxy for a Minecraft Server.

When the program is run within NetBeans, the program runs perfectly fine without any errors. However, when a jar is built and the program is run from the jar, when logging in to the Minecraft Server this error is thrown:

Error with SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userips' @ org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource:1452

Basically what it is supposed to do is Log a users IP, Username, Time and Date of login.

I am using Netbeans IDE 7.2.1 and building the jar with Maven to handle all dependencies.

I have commons-dbcp-1.4.jar, mysql-connector-java-5.1.22.jar, and commons-pool-1.5.4.jar imported into my Dependencies using maven, and they are in the jar file.

Here is the class where the connection is established:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;


public final class ConnectionPooler {

    public static final Configuration config = new Configuration();


    private static final BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();

    static {
        config.load();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl(config.sql_url);
        dataSource.setUsername(config.sql_user);
        dataSource.setPassword(config.sql_pass);
        dataSource.setInitialSize(5);
        dataSource.setMaxActive(30);
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return dataSource.getConnection();
    } 

}
```

And here is the class where the mysql query and all that are performed:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class IPLogger {



public boolean logip(String player, String ipp) throws SQLException {
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;


    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    TimeZone timeZone1 = now.getTimeZone();
    String timeZone = timeZone1.getDisplayName();
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    Date date1 = new Date();
    Date date2 = new Date();
    String date;
    String time;
    date = dateFormat.format(date1);
    time = timeFormat.format(date2);


    String SQL_EXIST = "INSERT INTO `proxyips` (`username`, `ip`,`date`,`time`) VALUES ('"+player+"', '"+ipp+"','"+date+"','"+time+" "+timeZone+"')";

    try{
        connection = ConnectionPooler.getConnection();
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_EXIST);
        statement.executeUpdate();

    } finally {
        if (resultSet != null) {
            try { resultSet.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {ignore.printStackTrace(); }
        }
        if (statement != null) {
            try { statement.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {ignore.printStackTrace(); }
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            try { connection.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {ignore.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    }       

    return true;
}

}
```

Here is the pom.xml in case I might have some errors with building or something like that:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>net.md-5</groupId>
    <artifactId>BungeeCordKC</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>BungeeCordKC</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                  <showDeprecation>false</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <configuration>

                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                                <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude>
                                <exclude>**/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>**/*.DSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>

                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Main-Class>${main.class}</Main-Class>
                            <Implementation-Version>${describe}</Implementation-Version>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <build.number>unknown</build.number>
        <main.class>net.md_5.bungee.BungeeCord</main.class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            <version>1.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>13.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-ext-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.47</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.22</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <type>jar</type>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

If anyone knows what is wrong, or if you have any questions regarding how I set up my environment please let me know.

EDIT: here is the full stack trace when I added that catch statement to the try block.

```
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:mysql://localhost.com:3306/use
rips'
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(Basic
DataSource.java:1452)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSou
rce.java:1371)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource
.java:1044)
        at net.md_5.bungee.ConnectionPooler.getConnection(ConnectionPooler.java:
30)
        at net.md_5.bungee.IPLogger.logip(IPLogger.java:44)
        at net.md_5.bungee.InitialHandler.run(InitialHandler.java:77)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.stackTraceToString(Util.java:355)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.<clinit>(Util.java:120)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.parseURL(NonRegisteringDriver.jav
a:764)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.acceptsURL(NonRegisteringDriver.j
ava:265)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(Basic
DataSource.java:1437)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't load resource bundle due to underly
ing exception java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base nam
e com.mysql.jdbc.LocalizedErrorMessages, locale en_US
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Messages.<clinit>(Messages.java:61)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name c
om.mysql.jdbc.LocalizedErrorMessages, locale en_US
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(Unknown Source
)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(Unknown Source)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Messages.<clinit>(Messages.java:59)
        ... 17 more
```

Comment: your query should be parameterized, eg `String SQL_EXIST = "INSERT INTO proxyips (username, ip,date,time) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";`

Comment: Don't forget to give your large try block a decent catch block, and I'm not talking about the catch blocks within the finally block as they don't count.

Comment: I guess I will remove the minecraft tag :P

Comment: Sorry about the Minecraft tag. I added a catch statement to the try block and edited the op with the stack trace.

Comment: Found the issue!!! :D Turns out that some .properties files needed for the mysql to work weren't in the .jar because of  <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude> . Thanks Hovercraft for telling me about adding that catch or else I would have never found out.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error is that you are excluding the `.properties` files when building the JAR with maven-shade. I would strongly recommend that you don't build big jars, but simply use the classpath mechanism as it is intended and keep drivers etc in their own jar file.

This is demonstrated by the following part of the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't load resource bundle due to underly
ing exception java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base nam
e com.mysql.jdbc.LocalizedErrorMessages, locale en_US
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Messages.<clinit>(Messages.java:61)
```

Resource bundles are also `.properties`.

So to fix this my first advice would be not to build one big jar, but otherwise, you will need to change the maven-shade exlusion filter by removing `<exclude>**/*.properties</exclude>` from:

```
<filters>
    <filter>
        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude>
            <exclude>**/*.SF</exclude>
            <exclude>**/*.DSA</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </filter>
</filters>
```

The reason it does work in your IDE is that there it uses the actual JAR files downloaded using maven.